# How to fix log-in in graphical mode on fedora 25

Tags: fedora, gnome, login

I run a fedora x86_64 within virtualbox. The host is windows 10.
After I made a (quite a few times actually) fresh new install of fedora workstation 25, I install a few things

```
#dnf group install "Development Tools"
#dnf update
```

install guest additions (but not consistent)

and I reboot : I end up at the login screen like so :[image]

When I click on my login, it fails to login (like, screen goes black and return to this state)
Same happens when I login typing the account name.
nb : I can log-in before updating.
I can however log-in in another tty (through terminal mode). (root graphical not working as well.)

The journalctl of a reboot + try to log graphically can be read here :

```
journalctl -b-0 | fpaste
```

[fpaste result](https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/CRC7QKSga7TKvPCr2IjAbV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=)

There seem to be some failure associated with gnome session desktop.

I tried to install kde, cinnamon, mate, sugar to be able to switch to another desktop manager, but I can't find any option to do so in the login screen, like I read I should.

I nevertheless found

```
/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service
```

but I can't find any other that I previously installed in here (I found some service in /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/, but I don't know whether or not it is pertinent.)

Any idea on how I can successfuly repair that stuff ?

Possible duplicate (without answers) : [Fedora 25: GNOME problem with logging back in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340412/fedora-25-gnome-problem-with-logging-back-in)

Quick update : Now a quick

```
#dnf update
```

seem to have resolve the trick a few days after anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mars 08 18:06:01 localhost.localdomain audit[1386]: AVC avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=1386 comm="gnome-shell" path=2F7661722F6C69622F67646D2F2331333131313636202864656C6574656429 dev="dm-0" ino=1311166 scontext=system_u:system_r:xdm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:xdm_var_lib_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

This is SELinux AVC message preventing to execute some file in the `/var/lib`, which is not allowed by the policy. There is [related bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1299402).

There are several things you can do about that. The easiest is to try again with SELinux in permissive mode (temporarily)

```
setenforce 0
```

If it is just throw-away virtual machine it should be ok. Otherwise, keep an eye on the logs if there will show up something new after the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can select Gnome-Xorg at logging in.
When logged in just run

```
gnome-shell --mode=user -r &
```

in the Terminal to start Gnome