# Can't login to fedora 25 gnome, except by using startx from tty

Tags: fedora, xorg, x-server, gdm, wayland

Last week fedora 25 gnome software center installed a buggy gdm version on my system, I removed it but still having problems. I'm using Gdm and Wayland session.

I can't login to fedora from login page, the only way is to use `tty`, login, then `startx`

I tried many solutions, including removing `Xauthority`, `chmod temp -R 755` or something and many other solutions but nothing worked.

What bother me the most is that I faced this same issue many years back on ubuntu and solved it but can't remember what I did! Hell I might have even solved it on Crunchbang many years ago!

the log file of `startx`

```
xauth:  file /home/user/.serverauth.1830 does not exist
X.Org X Server 1.19.1
Release Date: 2017-01-11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System:  4.10.0-0.rc4.git0.2.fc26.x86_64 
Current Operating System: Linux fedora 4.9.13-201.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 7 23:47:11 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.13-201.fc25.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/fedora-root ro rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Build Date: 01 February 2017  02:03:54AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.19.1-3.fc25 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sun Mar 12 14:37:10 2017
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
pkexec version 0.113
```

If it can't be solved, I'll switch to `lightdm` or `kdm`

Comment: Looks like related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350043/how-to-fix-log-in-in-graphical-mode-on-fedora-25/350049#350049

Comment: @Jakuje didn't work, just tried it. The log is still the same, unless you were referring to a different log then the one I'm showing in the question

Comment: Do you see some SELinux AVCs in audit?

Comment: @Jakuje this? http://pastebin.com/hDTGnujZ

Comment: First of all I would try with SELinux in permissive (`setenforce 0`).

Comment: @Jakuje I ran `sudo setenforce 0  ` before restarting my pc, then it didn't work then I went to `tty` ran it again and came back to login screen, still wasn't able to login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a billion solution, nothing worked, today I upgraded to Fedora 26, everything worked just fine, error fixed. No idea how, must be some buggy software that got fixed by the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> type=AVC msg=audit(1489481742.902:140): avc:  denied  { view } for  pid=1159 comm="gdm-session-wor" scontext=system_u:system_r:xdm_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:system_r:kernel_t:s0 tclass=key permissive=0

The AVC you posted points to this [bug #1378297](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1378297) already filled in the Red Hat bugzilla.

To make sure it is really the same problem, I would give it a try SELinux in permissive (running `seteonfoce 0` will not be effective over reboots). Modify `/etc/selinux/config` and change `enforcing` to `permissive` and then try to reboot.

The other possibility is to follow the steps in the report:

```
# ausearch -c 'gdm-session-wor' --raw | audit2allow -M my-gdmsessionwor
# semodule -X 300 -i my-gdmsessionwor.pp
```

and reboot. If it will help, nagging in the bugzilla to fix that is probably a way to go :)

Comment: I changed that now to `permissive`, I even reinstalled `gdm` and `gnome-shell`, rebooted,  same issue!